# void-variable latex-mode-abbrev-table

Tags: errors, emacs, auctex, mac

I'm using `auctex` + `Emacs`(OSX)

Problem: If I open an `LaTeX` file, it works right.
But if I open an `plain tex` file, it complains.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable latex-mode-abbrev-table)
  plain-TeX-common-initialization()
  plain-tex-mode()
  tex-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(tex-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
```

Comment: What is the complaint before going into debugger?  Also, how are you distinguishing a LaTeX file from a plain TeX file?  While I do use emacs, I don't use auctex.  So maybe that's where I'm not understanding things.  Nevertheless, knowing the actually message emacs is posting could be helpful.

Comment: I has to do with Emacs.app in OSX. It doesn't give a problem using the default emacs in Mac OSX. Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable latex-mode-abbrev-table)
  plain-TeX-common-initialization()
  plain-tex-mode()
  tex-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(tex-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer a.tex> "~/tmp/a.tex" nil nil "~/tmp/a.tex" (7676964 16777219))
  find-file-noselect("~/tmp/a.tex" nil nil nil)
  find-file("~/tmp/a.tex")
  command-line-1(("a.tex"))
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()

Comment: Emacs.app is probably a more recent version of emacs than the version you run from the terminal shell (at least that's what I assume you mean by "default emacs").  It would really help to know what the "Message" emacs reported was *before* you entered debugger.  Also, I'd recommend trying to load emacs without opening using your emacs profile to see what happens.  Then gradually add in the features from your profile until you find what's breaking things.

Comment: Finally, I don't understand how you have things set up to distinguish between a plain TeX file and a LaTeX file.  Unless `auctex` does something I'm unfamiliar with, emacs' `tex-mode` and `latex-mode` should pretty much be the same thing.  If anything, something that fails in `tex-mode` should also fail in `latex-mode`, not the other way around.  So, I suspect it's something to do with your emacs profile.

Comment: I still strongly suspect that there's something going on with your emacs profile.  It looks like debugger is complaining that it can't find the abbreviation table for `latex-mode`.  So you might look into whether you've disabled anything connected to loading the `tex-mode` defaults, which is required for `auctex` to get everything in `plain-tex` up and running.

Comment: Now the .emacs file:

Comment: Now the .emacs file:  load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t). I open a.tex (which is a plain tex file) It doesn't complaining now, and I press control-c, control-c, it says c-c c-c undefined, so I guess auctex is not loaded. The "Message" is:("/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-10.7" "a.tex")
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
File mode specification error: (void-variable latex-mode-abbrev-table)
Applying style hooks... done
This time, I open an latex file by Emacs b.tex, everything is fine, I can use c-c c-c to compile and to view.

Comment: There is a link: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX and specifically the part "Abbrev mode and AUCTeX". I followed it and put the lisp function in .emacs file but still no prevail.

Comment: Solution(?) At line 145 in "plain-tex.el":  (setq local-abbrev-table latex-mode-abbrev-table). I comment it out or change it to(setq local-abbrev-table text-mode-abbrev-table). Then it works for plain-tex mode. But don't understand abbrev-mode. Do we usually use this mode when editing tex file?

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug in AUCTeX, already [fixed in the development version](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=1a5d4475fb7c82dfca46dfdb39c9167ca8c624e7). You have to change the line 145 of `plain-tex.el` from

```lisp
(setq local-abbrev-table latex-mode-abbrev-table)
```

to

```lisp
(setq local-abbrev-table plain-tex-mode-abbrev-table)
```

Probably you'll also need to issue <kbd>M-x</kbd> `byte-compile-file` on that file.